Is there a name for this 2d shape made from the curves of 4 different ellipses?
4 ellipses
one quadrant in use from each ellipses
This is 2 dimensions of data, each one a distribution with a right skew, combined into one image.  Note, I'm not really showing probability, this is really just meant to show range.
Also, any ideas on how this would scale up to n-dimensions?  2 dimensions requires using 4 different bounded equations, I'm assuming 3 dimensions would require using 8 different bounded dimensions and so on.

Not the same, but close. Try searching for polycentric oval. Here's a book: https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/all-sides-to-an-oval

@Ethan Bolker  Thank you!  Another new term for me!  Honestly, I think it might be an asymmetric polycentric oval.  Does that seem right?
I'm using this for modeling a psychology theory, and it seems to make the math so much more complicated in, for example, 5 dimensions (where I would need 2^5 bounding statements).  Maybe I'll just stick with hyper-spheres and set notation to show intersection!

You're welcome. I can't imagine a model in psychology theory could really need algebraic surfaces of low degree. Smooth and convex with whatever symmetries your theory calls for should suffice.

For readers interests, the locus of centre of a Reuleaux triangle for drilling a square hole is also composed of four arcs from part of an ellipse.

I don't know if there is a specific name attached to this kind of curve made of $smoothly$ connected elliptical arcs.
But I would like to give here some details about similar curves that I have met when solving a recreational mathematics issue :
Question : a goat is tethered to a circular chain  sliding around $n$ (high enough...) metallic poles with feet $A_1,A_2,\cdots  A_n$. We can assume WLOG that these points constitute a convex polygon $(P)$); the total length of the chain is assumed of course larger than the perimeter of $(P)$. Question : describe the external boundary of the region that the goat can access.
Answer : it is closed curve made of smoothly connected ellipsoidal arcs with foci taken among the pairs $\{A_p,A_q\}$ due to the geometrical definition of the ellipse as the set of points $M$ such that $MF+MF'$=constant, being understood that, for any extreme position of the goat, in general, there are only two points $A_p, A_q$ where the chain "detaches" itself from the polygon.
Here is an illustration of this boundary curve in the case $n=3$ with different "level"-curves corresponding to different lengths of the chain.

The extended sides of the triangle are the limits of the areas where the different elliptical arcs are joined. Please note a trend to circularization, for large chain lengths, .
These curves have been obtained by considering the convex hull $(H_M)$ of the $n+1$ points $A_1,A_2,\cdots  A_n$ plus $M$, for a given position $M(x,y)$ not necessarily extremal, of the goat. Let
$$L(M)=L(x,y)$$ be the perimeter of convex hull $(H_M)$.
It suffices now to consider a series of level sets of function $L(x,y)$.
If you browse the Matlab program below, you will find the different "ingredients" mentionned above :
 clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal off;axis xy;
 L=1;axis([-L,L,-L,L])
 A=-0.2*i;B=0.5-0.2i;C=0.1+0.4i; % triangle with complex coord.
 n=20;
 [X,Y]=meshgrid(-1:1/n:1,-1:1/n:1); % grid of points with 1/n spacing
 per=sum(abs([B-C,C-A,A-B])); % triangle perimeter
 for K=1:2*n+1
    x=(K-n-1)/n;%  in interval [-1,1]
    for L=1:2*n+1
       y=(L-n-1)/n;% same thing for y
       M=x+i*y;Q=[A,B,C,M];
       I=convhull(real(Q),imag(Q)); % convex hull
       R=Q(I);R=[R,R(1)];
       Z(L,K)=sum(abs(diff(R))); % perimeter of conv. hull
    end;
 end;
 contour(X,Y,Z,per+0.05*(1:16));


Super interesting, thanks for your response!  How do convex hulls generalize to dimensions above 3?  Consider the (n-sphere in a n-cube problem)[https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=zwAD6dRSVyI]...  Once the cube starts to become "spiky," is it still considered convex?


The concept of convex hulls exists in nD because its definition "smallest convex including the given points" makes sense in any dimension. For example, Matlab allows to computennD convex hulls. 2) Besides, I am going to have a look at th video you mention?

